# How to apply bold style to a specific word in Excel file using Python?

Tags: python, excel, xlwt, pyexcelerator

I am using `pyexcelerator` Python module to generate Excel files. 
I want to apply bold style to part of cell text, but not to the whole cell.
How to do it?

Comment: Can you figure it out by creating such a file in Excel then reading it in with pyexcelerator?

Comment: `pyexcelerator` has long been superseded by `xlwt`.  Recent versions of `xlwt` support Rich Text, demonstrated in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149748/format-individual-characters-in-a-single-excel-cell-with-python/14248375).  For generating Excel 2007+ files (.xlsx), `xlsxwriter` is the way to go, and it also supports Rich Text.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example from Excel documentation:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
    .Value = "New Title"
    .Characters(5, 5).Font.Bold = True
End With
```

So the Characters property of the cell you want to manipulate is the answer to your question. It's used as Characters(*start*, *length*).

PS: I've never used the module in question, but I've used Excel COM automation in python scripts. The Characters property is available using win32com.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 
i actually want to know if this is possible using python language , excel supports it for sure , but i couldn't find any way to do it using python.

Comment: i won't be able to use it as i am using ubuntu , what i was looking for was may be some neat hack in pyexcelerrator module , because it does gives back biff record data , and other records applicable to cell.anyway i will give it a try if i am able to expose it as a web service.

Answer (score 2):

Found example here: [Generate an Excel Formatted File Right in Python](http://www.answermysearches.com/generate-an-excel-formatted-file-right-in-python/122/)

Notice that you make a font object and then give it to a style object, and then provide that style object when writing to the sheet:

```
import pyExcelerator as xl

def save_in_excel(headers,values):
    #Open new workbook
    mydoc=xl.Workbook()
    #Add a worksheet
    mysheet=mydoc.add_sheet("test")
    #write headers
    header_font=xl.Font() #make a font object
    header_font.bold=True
    header_font.underline=True
    #font needs to be style actually
    header_style = xl.XFStyle(); header_style.font = header_font
    for col,value in enumerate(headers):
        mysheet.write(0,col,value,header_style)
    #write values and highlight those that match my criteria
    highlighted_row_font=xl.Font() #no real highlighting available?
    highlighted_row_font.bold=True
    highlighted_row_font.colour_index=2 #2 is red,
    highlighted_row_style = xl.XFStyle(); highlighted_row_style.font = highlighted_row_font
    for row_num,row_values in enumerate(values):
        row_num+=1 #start at row 1
        if row_values[1]=='Manatee':
            for col,value in enumerate(row_values):
                #make Manatee's (sp) red
                mysheet.write(row_num,col,value,highlighted_row_style)
        else:
            for col,value in enumerate(row_values):
                #normal row
                mysheet.write(row_num,col,value)
    #save file
    mydoc.save(r'C:testpyexel.xlt')

headers=['Date','Name','Localatity']
data=[
['June 11, 2006','Greg','San Jose'],
['June 11, 2006','Greg','San Jose'],
['June 11, 2006','Greg','San Jose'],
['June 11, 2006','Greg','San Jose'],
['June 11, 2006','Manatee','San Jose'],
['June 11, 2006','Greg','San Jose'],
['June 11, 2006','Manatee','San Jose'],
]

save_in_excel(headers,data)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply..
but this code will highlight the entire cell text , or in other words it will apply style to entire cell,
while i want to highlight only specific words in the cell.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution which i had used for the same problem.

```
    import xlsxwriter
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r'C:\workspace\NMSAutomation_001\FMGGUIAutomation\Libraries\Frontend\new_STICKERS_Final.xlsx')
####### two different formats
    bold   = workbook.add_format({'font_name':'Tahoma', 'bold': True, 'font_size':14})
    normal = workbook.add_format({'font_name':'Tahoma', 'font_size':11})

######## value is my string, bold and normal are my two different formats
    segments = [bold, value[:9], normal, value[9:]]
    worksheet.write_rich_string('A1', *segments) # 'A1' is cell position
    workbook.close()
```