# Format individual characters differently within an Excel cell

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwt

I have a column in Excel 2013 containing letters and the digits 1,2,3 and 4 (representing pinyin pronunciations and tone values). They are all in the same font & format, but I would like to convert the numbers only to superscript. It does not seem that I can use any of Excel's built-in find-and-replace functionality to replace a single character in a cell  with its superscript version: the entire cell format gets changed. I saw a thread [Format individual characters in a single Excel cell with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149748/format-individual-characters-in-a-single-excel-cell-with-python) which apparently holds a solution, but that was the first time I had heard of Python or xlwt.

Since I have never used Python and xlwt, can someone give me a basic step-by-step set of instructions to install those utilities, customize the script and run it?

Sample:

```
Li1Shi4
Qin3Fat1
Gon1Lin3
Den1Choi3
Xin1Nen3
```

Script from other thread:

```
import xlwt

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1')

font0 = xlwt.easyfont('')
font1 = xlwt.easyfont('bold true')
font2 = xlwt.easyfont('color_index red')
style = xlwt.easyxf('font: color_index blue')

seg1 = ('bold', font1)
seg2 = ('red', font2)
seg3 = ('plain', font0)
seg4 = ('boldagain', font1)

ws.write_rich_text(2, 5, (seg1, seg2, seg3, seg4))
ws.write_rich_text(4, 1, ('xyz', seg2, seg3, '123'), style)

wb.save('rich_text.xls')
```

What is the syntax that will achieve the "find numbers and replace with superscript"? Is it a font or a style? The code from the other thread seems to manually input "seg1" , "seg2" , "seg3" etc. Or am I misunderstanding the code?

Thanks in advance. I am using Windows 8, 64 bit, Excel 2013.

Comment: If you've never used python before, you don't want to use python for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm bored and in a teaching mood, so, here's a long "answer" that also explains a little bit about how you can figure these things out for yourself in the future :)

I typed `abc123def` into a cell, and recorded a macro using the macro recorder.

This is where you should **always** start if you don't know what the correct syntax is.

In any case, I selected the numeric part of this cell, and right-clicked, format cell, change font to superscript.

This is what the macro recorder gives me. This is a lot of code. Fortunately, it's a lot of junk.

```vb
Sub Macro2()
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=3).Font  'Applies to the first 3 characters
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=4, Length:=3).Font 'Applies to the middle 3 characters
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = True
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=7, Length:=3).Font 'Applies to the last 3 characters
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
End Sub
```

What it represents is three blocks of formatting: the first is the first 3 characters that aren't changed, then the 3 that we applied superscript to, and then the last three characters.

Almost all of this is default properties, since I made no other changes, so I can revise it to this:

```vb
Sub Macro2()
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=4, Length:=3).Font
        .Superscript = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Now we can see that there are two important parts to this.  The first part is **how to specify which characters to format**.  This is done by refereing to a cell's `.Characters`:

```vb
ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=4, Length:=3).Font
```

So we can see that this macro refers to the characters in the positon 4-6 in the string "abc123def", or "123".

The next, obvious part is to assign the `.Font.Superscript` property is `True`.

Now you want to generalize this so that you can apply it anywhere.  The above code is "hardcoded" the `Start` and `Length` arguments.  We need to make it dynamic.  Easiest way to do this is to go 1 character at a time, and check to see if it's numeric, if so, apply the superscript.

```vb
Sub ApplySuperscriptToNumbers()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim str As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cl As Range

    '## Generally should work on any contiguous "Selection" of cell(s)
    Set rng = Range(Selection.Address)
    '## Iterate over each cell in this selection
    For Each cl In rng.Cells
        str = cl.Value
        '## Iterate over each character in the cell
        For i = 1 To Len(str)
            '## Check if this character is numeric
            If IsNumeric(Mid(str, i, 1)) Then
                '## Apply superscript to this 1 character
                cl.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=1).Font.Superscript = True
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH. I enjoy the challenge of learning new "stuff" but this was a bit too much of a big bite for me to take on by myself all at once. Now that you have shown me the logic and steps involved I think I understand it. And might be able to modify it for some other things I wanted to do. Much appreciated.