# Is there a way with openpyxl to print a single word **bold**?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I would like to print out an Excel Sheet, in which I'll have a column with a lot of text. Inside of this text I would like to highlight some specific words in bold?

['B1'] = text text text text text text text text **bold** text text text text

Till now I just found ways to change the hole cell 'B1' to another format. Does anybody have an idea how to highlight a single word in another way? e.g. another color, italic or line breaks?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Are you open to use `VBA` for this task?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The ability to apply multiple formats to cell with xlwt / openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429014/the-ability-to-apply-multiple-formats-to-cell-with-xlwt-openpyxl)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing workbooks with rich text in openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774757/editing-workbooks-with-rich-text-in-openpyxl)

Comment: Do you really want a solution in openpyxl only?

Comment: @Prasanna: Actually I'm a beginner with Python, so I'm open to any solution. Till now I haven't heard VBA, what would be the advantage of it?

Comment: @user8212173: I'm a beginner and don't know another way of working on Excel sheets. What else would be your suggestions?

Comment: VBA is the best choice here as it is integrated within MS Excel. You just need to write a simple subroutine to do this task. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618121/change-color-of-certain-characters-in-a-cell). If you want to use Python for this job, then you can use xlwt. Take a look at: [Format individual characters in a single Excel cell with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149748/format-individual-characters-in-a-single-excel-cell-with-python)

Comment: @cgm I have added an answer with VBA. Please see if it takes you in the right path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, since you are open to `VBA` solution too as per the comment - I'm giving you a minimal example on making a portion of text bold

```
Sub MakeTextBold()
' Assume that the required text is in cell A1
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
' Assume that the text you want to make bold starts from
' position 6 in your cell and number of char to be bold = 2
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=6, Length:=2).Font
     .FontStyle = "Bold"
    End With 
End Sub
```

You can build up on this example - by

1. Change the range to the required range
2. Find out ways of specifying start position and length of characters to be made bold etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is a case of adding ***rich text*** support in openpyxl which has been on hold for a while due to complexity issues explained in this [Q&A](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/openpyxl-users/rich$20text|sort:date/openpyxl-users/eFfAsdaTm8k/AUjIxflS4g0J) from the official openpyxl mailing list.

Rich Text differs from plain text in that it supports text formatting, such as **bold**, *italics*, and underlining, as well as different fonts, font sizes, and colored text. Currently, the latest version of openpyxl(2.5.1) does not support rich text.